# Place keyword so it is visible in the Outlook search bar from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to place a keyword from Excel into the search bar in Outlook.

I don't want to search for anything.

I referred to this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/ff869970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and tried this.

```
Dim OutApp As Object, wK As Worksheet, kWd As String
Set wK = Sheet1

kWd = Trim(wK.Range("D4").Value)

kWd = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = " & kWd

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'Searches the Inbox folder

Dim objSch As Outlook.Search
Const strS As String = "Inbox"
Const strTag As String = "SubjectSearch"
Set objSch = _
  OutApp.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strS, Filter:=kWd, Tag:=strTag)
```

On the last line I get:

> Run-time error 446: object doesn't support named arguments

[image]

Comment: Would help if you would `Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application` and reference Outlook in Tools > References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Application.ActiveExplorer.Search in a With block (Note: I couldn't find this in the Microsoft API documentation)

In your code, instead of this:

```
Dim objSch As Outlook.Search
Const strS As String = "Inbox"
Const strTag As String = "SubjectSearch"
Set objSch = _
   OutApp.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strS, Filter:=kWd, Tag:=strTag)
```

Use this:

```
With OutApp.ActiveExplorer
    .ClearSearch 'Remove the current search
    .Search kWd, olSearchScopeAllFolders 'Setup the new search
    .Display 'Run the search
End With
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828967/manipulating-outlook-search-box-with-excel-vba/55540491#55540491)

Comment: Thanks I have been waiting for solution since last 2 years

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to automate Outlook and search for a keyword in a folder. In that case you may consider using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

The `Table` class allows to filter items in the folder:

- [How to: Filter and Efficiently Enumerate Items in a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb612664.aspx)

If you need to search in multiple folders you need to use the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class:

- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer I just want to put a word from excel to the searchbar in outlook that's it. I don't want it to search anything. Is this possible via excel vba alone?

Comment: Nope. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

To access the function AdvancedSearch, the object should be of type Outlook.Search. Refer the sample at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx)

Comment: I am unable to accomplish this from excel would you mind to post a solution to this problem?