# Manipulating Outlook Search Box with Excel Vba

Tags: excel, outlook

I try to do searching in Outlook Main Search box with any string coming from any excel cell.

For example I have mail reference number in excel spreadsheet, firstly copy of reference and then open outlook (if its open firstly check), after paste in main search box in outlook and then see results.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1):

Here the Answer :) Please active Outlook library via "Tools > References" in VBA Editor.

```
Sub showMailviaRef()

Dim refCode As String ' define your reference

refCode = Selection ' Referance code selection in your excel sheet

With Outlook.ActiveExplorer

    .ClearSearch ' Clear previous search if any
    .Search refCode, olSearchScopeAllFolders
    .Display 'Shows search results

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this from the python side of things so sorry if this is no help but I believe you'd do

```
expl = Outlook.Explorers.Item(1)
expl.Search("asdf",1)
```

I used this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.search

Outlook.Explores.Item(1) returns a explorer type object being your main window and .Search is a method in of that object.